# Continuosly pressing a button in a traitsui -based GUI

Tags: enthought, traitsui

I'm building a GUI for a machine with Traits and TraitsUI. I would like the machine to perform an action as long as a button on the GUI is pressed and of course having the GUI not freeze and display the outcome of this continuous action, i.e. in a separate thread.

I can define in the class which inherits `HasTraits` a button and a function which performs the actions when the button is pressed (`def _button_fired:`), but it seems to me that the way the `_button_fired` is defined, the GUI actually waits for the button-pressing to be over before performing the "Action". As stated above, I would like it to execute a function the second I press the button and stop this function execution (or execute a different function) when I release the button.

You can take as an example [code snippet no. 7](http://docs.enthought.com/traitsui/_static/traits_thread.py) from Gael's [tutorial](http://docs.enthought.com/traitsui/tutorials/traits_ui_scientific_app.html#id12) and just imagine that while pressing the button, the counter should increase.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Hellbourne

Comment: Does this help?:
https://github.com/enthought/traitsui/blob/master/traitsui/wx/themed_window.py

Comment: It probably would, if I knew wx... By the way, the themed_window.py does not stand by its own without adding a `control = Instance ( wx.Window )` in the `ThemedWindow` class. So this is the wx way of doing event-handling, right? Can you comment with a link to a simple wx guide to actually test this left-click event-handling?

Comment: I did not mean to suggest that you use the module, but only to use the button up/down techniques that it uses, which on very quick look (maybe too quick!) looked to be wx-independent.

Comment: Yeah, they seem dependent. However, the concept is the same also in `enable.tools.drag_tool` or `chaco.tools.cursor_tool`, so I should be able to write my own adaptation.

Comment: If you are willing to drop down to enable you can definitely do it straightforwardly.

Comment: What do you mean by "drop down"?

Comment: Referring to the fact that enable is a low level package (and very powerful) and will take a bit of study.

Comment: As always, it is a matter of prioritization. Of course I would rather have a high level solution, but if worse comes to worst...